# Why is dmidecode showing maximum capacity of my ram memory to unknown? How can i I check max memory I could use?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, sony-vaio

I have Sony Vaio SVF14212SGB with currently installed memory 8GB. *4GB each slot.

From the [Sony Asia Product Website](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/svf14212sg), it said maximum memory 8GB. Because I was wondering is it 8GB for each slot or 8GB total, so I check in my 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 using `sudo dmidecode -t memory` but the result of the maximum capacity is unknown.

[image: result of dmidecode -t memory]

Why am I getting that result? While `sudo lshw -C memory` can not provide maximum capacity of memory.

Is there another way to find out how much memory I can put in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dmidecode` just reads the BIOS ROM tables and displays them. So if the BIOS doesn't give the maximum capacity, `dmidecode` can't show it. And `lshw` just uses `dmidecode` (or does a similar thing, internally) to get at this particular information, so it can't show you, either.

That should explain the "why I am getting this". As for "how can I find out how much memory I can put in", only the company that designed the motherboard knows. So contact them and ask, and while you are at it, mention that this information is missing from the BIOS tables, and the information on the website is ambigous. They may update their BIOS (or not, companies are often lazy), and they may tell you (or not).